# Overlay sidepanel inside div, not fixed

Tags: html, css, angular

On the page there is a container (header above it, nav to the left). It contains a grid.
On grid selection i want to show a sidepanel (on the right side, that shows up).

I cannot use fixed position - it should be inside that container AND scroll when body is scrolled.
It cannot be absolute position because it would ignore flexbox height and would not grow to fit the page and would break responsive height.
The sidepanel should overlay on top of the grid not push it to the side whe nit appears.

The panel would have roughly similar layout (flexbox):

```
<div class="content-panel-wrapper">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="vehicle-grid-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="magical-sidebar"></div>
```

No jQuery. It is a purely Angular 4 project.

Comment: You should be more explicit with your requirements.

Comment: More explicit how? I specified that it should be inside the flex container, overlay on top, not fixed and scrolls with the body.

Comment: Then you should post a code that implements all your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a combination of relative and absolute with flex, i managed to add the sidebar inside the container and to the right plus allowing it to overlay the content when visible.

html:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="content-panel-wrapper"></div>
    <ng-sidebar-container>
        <ng-sidebar>
        </ng-sidebar>
    </ng-sidebar-container>
</div>
```

css:

```
.main-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
ng-sidebar-container {
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.ng-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
}
```